# jQuery datatables display too slow - 10,000 rows (Client-Side)

Tags: javascript, datatables

I would like to improve performance for a website page that shows log list (~10000) using datatable, but it load all the data rows / large amounts of data at once.
I know server-side can resolve this problem, but I don't have enough time to refactoring.
Hope to find a way to Delay loading of the page on the client side or the infinite scrolling.

```js
var tableOption = {
  "bPaginate": true,
  'retrieve': true,
  'paging': true,
  "info": false,
  "order": [],
  "deferRender": true
};
var table = $('#table').DataTable(tableOption);
$(document).ready(function() {
  getFullRecord();
});

function getFullRecord() {
  var timezone = document.getElementById("timezone").value;
  var website = document.getElementById("website").value;
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  var ip = document.getElementById("ip").value;
  var status = document.getElementById("status").value;

  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: project + "/recordData",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
      "dateStart": dateStart,
      "dateEnd": dateEnd,
      "timezone": timezone,
      "website": website,
      "url": url,
      "ip": ip,
      "status": status
    },
    success: function(data) {
      var dataArray = JSON.parse(data.result);
      var execTime = JSON.parse(data.execTime);
      var resHTML = '';
      $.each(dataArray, function(i, item) {
        resHTML += htmlInfo["resHTML"];
      });
      $('#recordTable').html(trHTML);
      table = $('#table').DataTable(tableOption);
    },
    error: function(data) {}
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>


<table id="table" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-sm ">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th id="timestamp" class="columnWidth" scope="col">Timestamp</th>
      <th class="columnWidth" scope="col">Status / Message</th>
      <th class="columnWidthXs" scope="col">Method</th>
      <th class="columnWidthXs" scope="col">Website</th>
      <th class="columnWidth" scope="col">URL</th>
      <th class="columnWidthSmall" scope="col">IP</th>
      <th class="columnWidthSmall" scope="col">cert</th>
      <th class="columnWidthMax" scope="col">Request </th>
      <th class="columnWidthMax" scope="col">Response </th>
      <th class="columnWidthMax scope=" col ">Host / Instance </th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody id="recordTable ">
     </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: Server-side would be best (e.g. using paging: only return 100 entries at once). At Client-side have a look at virtual scrolling.

Comment: Maybe your end users don't need all 10.000 lines displayed at a time? I mean who is going to read each one of these 10.000 lines? Surely you can implement a filter, or at least a pagination system.

Comment: Are you sure it's DataTables that's hurting the performance?  You also seem to be looping over the AJAX results and concatenating HTML strings, though it's really not clear what exactly you're doing with the AJAX results since `htmlInfo` isn't defined anywhere.  And what is `trHTML`?  It looks like you're not even using the AJAX results in the table?  If the intent is to use those results in the table, why not use the DataTables built-in functionality to fetch JSON data instead of manually crafting the HTML (which is slow) and re-initializing the table?

Comment: using Array map will improve speed over `$.each` significantly - though, to be honest, the main delay is waiting for the data to complete loading - I can imagine 10,000 rows of anything will be fairly sizable

Comment: I tracked execution time about HTML String concatenating and datatable. 
HTML String  spend time is 5757ms,  but datatable  is 17701ms.
Backend call API get resource and process jsonString.
FrontEnd get json use ajax , then concatenating HTML Strings because of need to add attribute like collapse/fold feature.

Comment: "<td class = 'columnWidthMax'>"
    + "<a class='collapse' href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='switchShow(this)' style='display:none; margin-right:5px;' status=''>"
    + "<img src='static/images/plus.png'></a>"
    + "<span style='width: 150px;display:inline-block;overflow:hidden;white-space:nowrap;text-overflow:ellipsis'>"
     +response
    +"</span>"
   + "</td>"